# Domain transformation

Tags: integration

Let $\Omega$ be a 2D domain with boundary $\Gamma$. Suppose its boundary can be parametrised by a smooth function $\phi:I \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $I:=[0,1]$. I know the following transformation holds:

$$
\int_{\Gamma(\phi)} f\ {\rm d}\Gamma = \int_{I} (f \circ \phi(t)) |\phi(t)'| \ {\rm d}t.
$$

But how does one transforms the integrals
$$
\int_{\Omega(\phi)} f \ {\rm d}\Omega, \qquad \int_{\Omega(\phi)} \nabla f \ {\rm d}\Omega
$$
over $I$?

Answer (score 0):

A two-dimensional surface integral of the divergence $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}$ of a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ can be written in terms of a one-dimensional integral over the parameterized boundary using Gauss' theorem: For a parametrization $\phi(t)=(u(t),v(t))$ of $\Gamma$, the unit vector normal to $\Gamma$ is 
$$\hat{n}(t)=\frac{\bigl(-v'(t),u'(t)\bigr)}{|\phi'(t)|}.$$ 
Then Gauss' theorem gives
$$\int_\Omega \nabla\cdot \mathbf{F} \,d\Omega=\int_\Gamma f\cdot\hat{n}\,d\Gamma= \int_{I} (\mathbf{F} \circ \phi(t)) \cdot\bigl(-v'(t),u'(t)\bigr) \ {\rm d}t.$$

The integral $\int f\,d\Omega$ in the OP can be calculated in this way by writing $f=\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}$ for a suitable $\mathbf{F}$, which is always possible, taking for example, $\mathbf{F}(x,y)=\bigl(0,\int_0^y f(x,y')dy'\bigr)$.